# Where to put script for generating java sources in maven structure?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

In one project (http://jodd.org) we have some classses generated by python scripts. Those are some big classes that has utility methods with similar behavior for all primitives and Object; we just wanted to simplify life and avoid potential errors made by repeating similar code.

Also note that this scripts are invoked manually, so we do NOT need any automation process etc.

We are mavenizing the project, and these scripts fall in the **src/main/resources** folder. Therefore, they become part of distributed jar with other resources, which is what we want to avoid.

What would be the standard maven location for these files; so they not become part of the distro jar? Is it **src/main/scripts** or **src/main/python**, or we should simply put them outside, in e.g. **etc** folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good place to put python scripts is in **src/main/python** as you described. Doing so, they won't be copied to the final jar. I use similar approach with some native codes written in C in my projects.

Comment: Just tried, it works as you said. Will wait somewhat more if there is some idea we didn't see.

Comment: This is the right way to achieve what you want. use src\main\language for each language (except js/css for a WAR but that's another problem) : flex, php, python, scala, ...